# Bootstrap 4 + Autoprefixer = Broken legacy iPads

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4, autoprefixer

```css
.row {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

So...bit of a weird issue. We have recently adopted Bootstrap 4 and the Flex model at my company, and we are noticing some weirdness when Bootstrap and Autoprefixer work in tandem.

Specifically, iPad version 8 or below just isn't having ANY of it. I know the specific attribute at fault, it's `display: -webkit-box;`. I can add `/* autoprefixer: off */` to the selector (.row) at fault to prevent all autoprefixing on that class, but I really don't want to change the bootstrap core files, and I'm thinking it would be wise to leave the rest of the prefixes for other browser support.

I can't think of a way to gracefully override/remove that `display: -webkit-box` attribute specifically. Any ideas from the audience? Is there some customization within autoprefixer that I'm missing? Answers appreciated in advance!

Comment: possible guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35137085/3597276

Comment: Thanks alot buddy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, it was right in front of my face, as I figured it was.

Autoprefixer has an option you can add to the gulp task:

`flexbox: "no-2009",`

Add that and it keeps the `-ms-flexbox` and `-ms-flex-wrap` attributes and removes the `display: -webkit-box` one.

Hopefully this helps anyone struggling in the future.

Check the "Disabling" section on the Github readme for Autoprefixer: 
https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#disabling